# Do you know a good tutorial for helping me to learn to introduce to my app the facebook login button?

Tags: xcode

can you help me with  a good tutorial or codes , please?

Comment: So you are asking about integrating login using signup right?

Comment: yes , that is what i want to know

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources but it should be an authentic resource as it is an integral step of any website or application. The order is according to the authenticity.

1) https://developers.facebook.com/products/login

2) https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837

3) https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_facebook_login.htm

Comment: i install coco poads and i get error everytime and it doesn't find my project